# How to set IS_NOT_EMPTY and string (not included 0-9) in web2py data structure

Tags: python, web2py, web2py-modules

I am developing web2py - Models - db_testing.py in pythonanywhere.com

below code is running successfully:

```html
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
db = DAL('sqlite://storage.sqlite')
db.define_table('registration',
    Field('firstname', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY(error_message='Should not left blank')),
    Field('lastname', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
    Field('gender', requires=IS_IN_SET(['Male', 'Female'])),
    Field('birthday', 'date'),
    Field('email', requires = IS_EMAIL(error_message='invalid email!')),
    Field('salary', 'integer'),
    Field('seniority', 'integer')
    )
```

However, the first field 'firstname' can only prevent form filling not to left blank. It cannot validate the input is in a-z or A-Z.

The last field 'seniority' can assure form filling must be 0-9, but it cannot prevent form filling not to left blank.

How can I set both requirements (IS_NOT_EMPTY with error_message and assure input is string / integer)?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the [documentation](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#Validators), the `requires` attribute of a `Field` can be a list of validators. So, you can do something like this:

```
Field('firstname', requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY(), IS_ALPHANUMERIC()])
```

To limit to just letters, use `IS_MATCH` with a regular expression:

```
Field('firstname', requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY(), IS_MATCH('^[a-zA-Z]+$')])
```

Above, you do not necessarily need the `IS_NOT_EMPTY` validator, as the regular expression in `IS_MATCH` requires at least one letter, but you may want to keep `IS_NOT_EMPTY` in order to display a different error message specifically for empty responses.

Comment: IS_ALPHANUMERIC() include a-z, A-Z and 0-9. Is it possible to exclude 0-9?

Comment: See updated answer. All of the validators are documented in the book: http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#Validators

Answer (score 0):

To check whether it's a string: `if isinstance(firstname, str)`

To check whether non-empty: you can do `if firstname != ''` or `if firstname`; in Python, empty objects are treated as being "False" when used as a boolean. To check whether it's letter characters, you can do `if firstname.isalpha()`.

Comment: How to set and combine both str and !="" in web2py data structure?